# Java template class that takes an array; any way to enforce that?

Tags: java

I'm writing a template class which should take an array as its type.

```
public class Foo<T> {...}
```

How best can I enforce that "T" is an array type? (int[], Bar[], ...) Preferably compile time if possible, obviously, but otherwise what is the best way at debug run time to throw an exception or something if T is not an array?

Comment: I didn't think you could.  For example, I don't think List<string[]> would compile.  You should make it an array type yourself in code by using T as T[].

Comment: List<String[]> is valid and will compile; test before thinking :). It's a list of String arrays, like a 2D array. Why didn't you think that would be valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do it exactly how you have asked and have the generic type specify an array or primitive.

The syntax allows for things like:

```
public class Foo <az09$_ extends MyClassOrInterface & Serializable & Closeable> {...}
```

Where az09$_ is any valid identifier that may also be parameterized with an identically formatted generic type.

But az09$_ is restricted to being a java identifier, so you cannot do `public class Foo<T[]> {...}` any more than you can do `public class Foo[] {...}`.

Typically you would do what you are after in your usage of T, i.e:

```
public class Foo<T> {

    public T[] processIt(T... ts) {
        // do something
        return ts;
    } 

}
```

Comment: This is not a correct answer to the question, at least not as asked.  This guarantees that the processIt method is passed an array of T objects, which is quite different from ensuring that T itself is an array.

Comment: The result, in my case, is the same though. I think this is a good point and I'll accept it. For some reason I wasn't thinking of T being the array element type rather than the array type, and of course requiring T[] in the constructor (or wherever) does indeed enforce an array of T.

Comment: @LordArtemis Fair enough.  Added the explicit "no you cannot do that exactly as asked" information.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to agree and extend [David Blevin's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400649/java-template-class-that-takes-an-array-any-way-to-enforce-that/3400692#3400692) answer.  You can put MyClass inside a factory class and make the constructors of MyClass private.  This way only code within the factory class can directly instantiate a MyClass. It is up to you to make sure they do the right thing.  You can either make the factory clas parameterized (as below) or make the make method itself parameterized.

```
// T is the component type of the array
public class MyClassFactory < T >
{
      // we can't directly enforce TARRAY=T[], but TARRAY=T[]
      public final class MyClass < TARRAY > 
      {
            private MyClass ( ... arguments ) throws ... exceptions { ... code }
            // no non private constructors
            .... more code
      }

      // this is the only way to construct a MyClass
      // so we indirectly enforced TARRAY=T[]
      public MyClass<T[]> make ( ... arguments ) throws ... exceptions 
      {
            return new MyClass <T[]>( ... arguments ) ;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to check if the type is an array, it can be done at runtime with the following code, though this is a bit of a hack and not exactly efficient:

```
public static boolean isArrayType (Object o) {
    return o.getClass().isArray();
}
```

Ultimately it depends on exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: For that approach, clazz.isArray() + clazz.getComponentType() get you all the array info.

Comment: Thanks!  I fixed the answer to use your method, which is by all means a better way than what I had used.

Answer (score 0):

@emory is on the right track for a clean way to do this without runtime checks.  Personally I'd be concerned with readability of the type name - here's a very compact example using inner classes and I think the resulting type name at the end is very readable.

```
public static class Bar {}
public static class Foo<T> {
    public static class Array<TA> {
        private Array() {}
    }
    public Array<T[]> make() {
        return new Array();
    }
}
Foo.Array<Bar[]> fooray = new Foo<Bar>().make();
```